# How to ignore NA when using paste in R

Tags: r, dplyr, paste, stringr

in R, Let's say I have strings like:

```
str0 <- NA
str1 <- c("aaa")
str2 <- NA
str3 <- c("bbb")
str4 <- NA
```

when I do:

```
paste(str0, str1, str2, str3, str4, sep=',')
```

I got:

```
,aaa,,bbb,
```

But what I really need is:

```
aaa,bbb
```

So how can I ignore the comma at begin, at last and at the middle (more then 2 commas)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `vec <- c(str0, str1, str2, str3, str4)` and then `paste(na.omit(vec), collapse = ",")`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you, Ronak! I was stuck at this for a long time, I did not succeed with your method because str0-str4 in my program is another concatenated string, but I was using collapse, hence, in the end, it is not technically a "na.omitable" string, then I switched to sep=',' at last by which time I firstly use collapse=',', problem solved! thank you for inspiration!